# JupyterLab in a psychology experiment where participants use JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I'm preparing a series of experiments investigating how people learn while interacting with JupyterLab.

Like any psychology experiment, this will require *experimental control*, meaning that I need disable parts of the interface to prevent participants from going off task during the study.

It would also be helpful to put JupyterLab in a particular state for each user, e.g. extensions active and tabs/panes in a particular layout.

Any suggestions along the above would be appreciated. I have previously set up a JupyterHub (TLJH) and developed an extension, so I have some background knowledge on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use workspaces to 'setup' Jupyterlab when participants first come in? They're stored as json files (you can find the workspace directory using `jupyter lab paths`).

You can disable extensions with `jupyter labextension disable <extension name>`, even the non listed ones such as the filebrowser.

I think you will need to add your own extension too, to remove some of the 'elements' you don't want or re-organise them (such as some buttons in the toolbars, etc.).